# Can I install BOTH eclipse and android studio?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am a beginner in android development.
I started working with eclipse, but I want to experience android studio as well.
will the combination of both IDE's on my computer cause problems?
or can I use them both?

Comment: Whoever down-voted this question, I would love an explanation - just so I don't ask a silly question again!

Comment: I haven't downvoted but I can say that the reason for downvote is "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center." (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: OK I'll take that into consideration next time.. 10x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, here is how you can import your Eclipse project into Android Studio: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, I have both installed too and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can install both IDE's and try it out (installing both IDE's shouldn't cause any problems). I'm also currently trying out Android studio. On my personal opinion Eclipse is (still) better for Android development because Android studio is still in it's early stages (that doesn't mean that You can't use it for your app development). Also You can look at this [video from Google IO 2013](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmv1dTnhLH4) where they talk about new stuff in Android studio and do a bit of comparison with Eclipse (not much).

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain that it will cause no problems. I have used Eclipse and Netbeans on the same computer before, so if there is a problem with using both, it is specific to those IDEs.